# Is an involutive $*$- preserving map an antihomomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $*$-algebra and $\phi: A \mapsto A$ be a map such that $\phi(x)^*=\phi(x^*)$ and $\phi\circ \phi=id$. Is it then true that $\phi$ will be an antihomomorphism? Do I need more assumptions on $\phi$?

In fact my $\phi$ is of the form $\phi=T\psi T^{-1}$ where $T: A \to A$ is an isomorphism of underlying vector space of $A$ and $\psi$ is a $*$ preserving antihomomorphism and is involutive. Will then $\phi$ be an antihomomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.  For example, if $p\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a nontrivial projection, then
$$
\phi(a)=a-2pap
$$
is a counter example.

---

Edit: Another counter example is the identity map on any noncommutative star algebra.

Comment: In fact my $\phi$ is of the form $\phi=T\psi T^{-1}$ where $T: A \to A$ is an isomorphism of underlying vector space of $A$ and $\psi$ is a $*$ preserving antihomomorphism and is involutive. Will then $\phi$ be an antihomomorphism?

Comment: Without further assumptions on $T$, I think this is highly unlikely.

Comment: I tried further to derive the following relations among $T,\phi$ and $ \psi$. 1. $T(x)^*=T\circ \psi(x^*)$ 2. $T^{-1}(y^*)=\psi (T^{-1}(y))^*$ 3. $(T^{-1}(y))^*=T^{-1}\circ \phi(y^*)$. Still I am not able to prove it.